# Controlling Overlay in ggplot depending on which type is selected

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, overlay

For reproducible data, I'm attaching this similar example at: http://zevross.com/blog/2019/04/02/easy-multi-panel-plots-in-r-using-facet_wrap-and-facet_grid-from-ggplot2/

Fast forwarding to the line: "Combining color and faceting can also be effective", my question is that code is probably ordered like below

| Sex | Date | good_bad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | 2000 | y |
| M | 1980 | n |
| F | 1964 | y |
| M | 1955 | y |
| F | 1980 | n |

...and so on...

```
ggplot(data = marvel_count, aes(year, n, color = gender)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "New Marvel characters by alignment & gender",
       subtitle = "(limited to characters with more than 100 appearances)",
       y = "Count of new characters", x = "")+ 
  facet_grid(. ~ align)
```

My question is can we control the overlay? Can I have it only show females, males, and both? I supposed that it would have some tweaks to **color** (I'm using **type** in my code, ie. type = gender). I want a variable that can control this.

Please let me know if this is possible, need another code design for the graph, or point me in the right direction! I was unable to find resources relating to this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Change the `filter` input

If you look at the code leading to the plot, you can notice the `filter` function that filter the data frame keeping the "Male" and "Female". So if you wanted to plot only the females, you can directly modify this filter to have only *"Female "*

```
marvel_count <- filter(marvel_count, gender%in%c("Female ", "Male ")) %>% 
  mutate(gender = factor(gender, levels = c("Male ", "Female ")))

marvel_count <- filter(marvel_count, gender%in% c("Female "))
```

And then run the code to generate the plot:
[image]

#### `Subset` directly from your data

Another option would be to directly subset the variable you want to show on the plot within the ggplot line (which will result in the same graph as above)

```
ggplot(data = subset(marvel_count, gender == "Female "), aes(year, n, color = gender)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "New Marvel characters by gender",
       subtitle = "(limited to characters with more than 100 appearances)",
       y = "Count of new characters", x = "")
```

[image]

#### Dividing the plots with `facet_wrap`

If you just want to distinguish the two groups, you can split in multiple plots and keeping the colours by adding the `facet_wrap(~gender)`

```
ggplot(data = marvel_count, aes(year, n, color = gender)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~gender)+
  labs(title = "New Marvel characters by gender",
       subtitle = "(limited to characters with more than 100 appearances)",
       y = "Count of new characters", x = "")
```

[image]

#### Based on a variable

Lastly, to answer your question on how to achieve the filtering based on a variable, here is one option:
You could create a variable that you define for the filtering and then pass this into the filtering:

```
Filter_gender = c("Male ", "Female ")
marvel_count <- filter(marvel_count, gender %in% Filter_gender )
```

And then run the same code as previously to plot:

```
ggplot(data = marvel_count, aes(year, n, color = gender)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "New Marvel characters by gender",
       subtitle = "(limited to characters with more than 100 appearances)",
       y = "Count of new characters", x = "")
```

[image]

The issue with this is if you change for a single gender the colour would be the same for both, for example if you set `Filter_gender` on *"Male "*:

```
Filter_gender = c("Male ")
marvel_count <- filter(marvel_count, gender %in% Filter_gender )

ggplot(data = marvel_count2, aes(year, n, color = gender)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point() + 
  labs(title = "New Marvel characters by gender",
       subtitle = "(limited to characters with more than 100 appearances)",
       y = "Count of new characters", x = "")
```

[image]

One way to workaround that and keep the colour coding consistent is to select the color for each gender:

```
df_col = data.frame(gender=c("Female ", "Male "), col=c("#F8766D", "#00BFC4"))
   gender     col
1 Female  #F8766D
2   Male  #00BFC4
```

And then to filter based on the variable you choose to plot and attribute the colours with `scale_colour_manual`:

```
Filter_gender = c("Male ")
marvel_count <- filter(marvel_count, gender %in% Filter_gender )

df_col = filter(df_col, gender %in% Filter_gender)

ggplot(data = marvel_count, aes(year, n, color = gender)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = df_col$col)+
  labs(title = "New Marvel characters by gender",
       subtitle = "(limited to characters with more than 100 appearances)",
       y = "Count of new characters", x = "")
```

[image]

See below, the same plot if you change `Filter_gender = c("Male ")` to `Filter_gender = c("Female ")`

[image]

So with this option you just have to determine `Filter_gender` and the filtering and colouring will be done accordingly.

Comment: Thank you ver much! This was very informative and I will begin to incorporate it into my code!